# How to set WooCommerce product attribute programatically?

Tags: woocommerce

This is regarding gravity form advance post creation. I am using gravity form to add WooCommerce products. I cannot map gravity form checkboxes field to product attributes(taxonomy based attribute). I need to know is there a way that I can connect gravity field to product attribute programatically.

I have tried this:

```
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ATTRIBUTE_VALUE', 'pa_ATTRIBUTE', true );
$thedata = Array(
     'pa_ATTRIBUTE'=>Array( 
           'name'=>'pa_ATTRIBUTE', 
           'value'=>'ATTRIBUTE_VALUE',
           'is_visible' => '1',
           'is_variation' => '1',
           'is_taxonomy' => '1'
     )
);
update_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'_product_attributes',$thedata);
```

Comment: Since its premium addon you should contact the author if they support it. In quick search on the web i see many comments that its not supported.